# Problem by designing and filtering a Bessel-Thomson filter in Python

Tags: python, filter-design

I have an issue when I want to filter a signal with a 4th order Bessel-Thomson filter with a cutoff frequency at 18 GHz.

**1. Generate data at 50 Gbps (T-spaced)**

```
def prbs_generation(number_symbol=-1, size=15, oversampling_factor=100, bitrate=50, plot=False, save=False):
"""
Generate a PRBS
:param number_symbol: number of symbol, -1 means full PRBS
:param size: size of the PRBS (7, 15, ...)
:param oversampling_factor: oversampling factor (100 to be close to a continuous signal)
:param bitrate: bitrate in Gbps
:param plot: Authorized plotting
:param save: Authorized saving
:return: bit_oversampled & t in ps
"""

print("Generation of the PRBS ...")
bit = list()
start = 1
lfsr = start
i = 1

while True:
    fb = ((lfsr >> (size-1)) ^ (lfsr >> (size-2)) & 1)
    lfsr = ((lfsr << 1) + fb) & (2 ** size - 1)
    bit.append(fb)
    if lfsr == start or i == number_symbol:

        break
    i = i + 1

bit = [float(i) for i in bit]

if number_symbol != -1:
    length = number_symbol
else:
    length = 2**size-1

for i in range(length):
    bit[i] = 2 * (bit[i] - 0.5)

# "Continuous" signal
g = np.ones(oversampling_factor)
bit_oversampled = np.zeros(len(bit) * oversampling_factor)
bit_oversampled[::oversampling_factor] = bit
bit_oversampled = signal.lfilter(g,1, bit_oversampled)
t_oversampled = np.arange(0, len(bit_oversampled)) * (1000 / (bitrate * oversampling_factor))

return bit_oversampled, t_oversampled
```

**2. Design a filter the signal**

```
def Bessel_Thomson_filtering(data, t, Fc=18.75, order=4, btype='low', analog='True', plot=True, save=False):

Wn = Fc                     # Cutoff frequency

# Design a Bessel-Thomson filter
b, a = signal.bessel(order, Wn * 2 * np.pi, btype=btype, analog=analog, norm='mag')

# Filter the signal
data_filtered_1 = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)

if plot:
    w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)
    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogx(w/(2*np.pi), 20*np.log10(np.abs(h)))
    plt.scatter(Wn, -3, color='red')
    plt.title('Bessel filter magnitude response', fontweight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency, GHz')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude, dB')
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.tight_layout()

    if save:
        plt.savefig("bessel_frequency_response.png")

    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogx(w, np.unwrap(np.angle(h)))
    plt.title('Bessel filter phase response', fontweight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency, GHz')
    plt.ylabel('Phase, radians')
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.tight_layout()

    if save:
        plt.savefig("bessel_phase_response.png")

    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(t, data, s=3, label='Original data')
    plt.scatter(t, data_filtered_1, s=1, label='Filtered data moi')
    plt.title("PRBS filtered at " + str(Fc) + " GHz", fontweight='bold')
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    #plt.ylim([-2, 2])
    plt.xlim([-10, 1200])
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()

    if save:
        plt.savefig("data_filtered.png")
```

**3. Example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
from telecom import filterTheSignalWithBessel

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Generate data
data, t = prbs_generation()

# Bessel-Thomson filtering
Bessel_Thomson_filtering(data, t, plot=True)
```

When I plot the original data and the filtered on the same figure, I got this:

[image]

Do you have any idea where could be my issue?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you fix your code? You're not returning the `t` from `prbs_generation()`. Please make sure someone can copy and paste your code and run it. As is, it gives errors.

Comment: As for your question, it seems you'd want the cut-off to be in $\tt{GHz}$: `Bessel_Thomson_filtering(data, t, Fc=18.75e9, ...)`

Comment: Thanks @Jdip ! Done ! ;)

Comment: [lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) needs a **digital** filter. You're using an analog filter as input. [signal.bessel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bessel.html) can be designed to be digital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate or simulate an analog signal, but it lives inside your computer, so by definition is digital.

You can only filter a **digital** signal using a **digital** filter. If you’re only interested in looking at the behavior of the analog filter, then you can leave the analog design that you had (careful with the cutoff frequency though, should be $18.75 \tt{GHz}$, not $18.75 \tt{Hz}$) but you cannot use this to actually filter your signal.

---

If you want to filter your signal:

1. You need a **digital** filter.
2. You need to set the **normalized** cut-off frequency accordingly.
3. You should always use cascaded second order sections when designing filters with higher orders.

With that in mind:

```py
def Bessel_Thomson_filtering(data, t, Fc=18.75e9, order=4, btype='low', analog=False, plot=True, save=False):

    Wn = Fc/(50e9/2) # normalized Cutoff frequency

    # Design a Bessel-Thomson filter with cascaded second order sections
    sosbessel = signal.bessel(order, Wn, btype=btype, analog=analog, norm='mag', output='sos')

    # Filter the signal
    data_filtered_1 = signal.sosfilt(sosbessel, data)
```

There are other problems with this (ringing artifacts, etc) but at least the implementation is now corrected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't understand the difference between the analogic & the digital filter. The idea behind that is that I want to simulate a "continuous" signal that I will sample later.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer with precisions ;)